# Merging intersecting list elements

Tags: r, list, merge, reduce, intersect

I have a list of `R` `integer` `vector`s which some elements are redundant and others intersect each other:

```
ll <- list(c(1,4), c(5,7,3,9), c(5,3,7,9), c(2,7,10), 8, 6)
```

The `integer`s in the `vector` elements are just indices and not ranges, and the order of the elements in the list is arbitrary.

I'm looking for a function that'll return a `list` that'll merge `ll`'s intersecting elements and remove the redundancy.

For the example `ll` above this function will return:

```
list(c(1,4), c(2,3,5,7,9,10), 6, 8)
```

Any idea?

Unfortunately, the solution offered by @alexis_laz in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944232/how-to-merge-overlapping-integer-vector-elements-of-a-list-in-r) doesn't solve my problem because it assumes that the list is ordered, which is not my case.

For example, if I change the order of `ll`'s elements:

```
ll <- list(c(2,7,10), c(1,4), c(5,7,3,9), 8, 6, c(5,3,7,9))
```

@alexis_laz's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944232/how-to-merge-overlapping-integer-vector-elements-of-a-list-in-r) doesn't hold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge overlapping integer vector elements of a list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944232/how-to-merge-overlapping-integer-vector-elements-of-a-list-in-r)

Comment: Not exactly. In that post the vectors are ranges and the solution is rather specific to that. In my case the vectors are just integers/indices but and their actual value doesn't have a specific meaning.

Comment: Would you mind try @alexis_laz's answer that's accepted in that question? It works with your case, giving similar result, just including some empty elements in list.

Comment: I think it's not exactly it because @alexis_laz's answer is only testing for intersections between consecutive elements in the list. In my case I'm looking for intersections between any pair of elements rather than only consecutive ones.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty messy but it my works for your case.

```
library(dplyr)

for (i in 1:(length(ll)-1)){
  if (!is.null(unlist(ll[i])) & length(ll) > i){
    for (j in length(ll):(i+1)) {
      if (length(intersect(ll[[i]], ll[[j]])) > 0 ){
        ll[[i]] <- union(ll[[i]], ll[[j]])
        ll <- ll[-j]
      }
    }
  }
}

[[1]]
[1] 1 4

[[2]]
[1]  5  7  3  9  2 10

[[3]]
[1] 8

[[4]]
[1] 6
```

Comment: Thanks. I think there needs to be a `while(max(table(unlist(ll)) > 1))` condition wrapping this solution because a single iteration over it might introduce new intersections.